# What are margins in designing for Samsung s8 apps?

Tags: user-interface, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, adobe-xd

I am designing an app for Samsung s8 screen size but it is not fit for example clock on the top bar is hidden

Comment: which artboard size are you working with?

Comment: 360 x 740 dp from https://material.io/tools/devices/ reference